# Firefox redirects askubuntu.com to google.com

Tags: discussion, firefox

On 16.04 with Firefox, whenever I try to go to askubuntu.com, I'm redirected to google.com ! This is true if I type the address in the url or if I click on the askubuntu logo on this site.

Notice that going to a specific question works...

Is there an ongoing problem on the site, or is the problem on my side ?

[EDIT] So, this is a firefox specific problem, as things work fine in Ubuntu Browser. I tried a new profile (firefox -P) and things work here too. So this is a profile specific problem. I've tried to find the core cause, and after googling a bit, I found this question https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox

So I cleared askubuntu.com history (forget about this site) and the redirection is gone... I still don't know how it first came, but now I know about the http 301 answer :-)

Comment: I think it's just you, try starting a new firefox profile (type `firefox -p` in a terminal and select new profile to launch) and see if the problem persists. BTW, I think this is a meta question.

Comment: Problem on your side or with your ISP. Change your settings to use  your own DNS server like google's public dns or opendns

Comment: I tried with Ubuntu Web Browser, and things work fine. So dns is ok, it's really related to my Firefox settings... maybe a plugin ? I'm investiging it further...

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this issue with the following steps:

1. determine if the problem is Firefox specific: I tried with Ubuntu Web Browser, and everything was fine, so it is Firefox specific (so there no dns problem for example)
2. determine if the problem is Profile specific: I tried with a new profile (using `firefox -P` to create a test profile), and it worked, so it is profile specific
3. then I found this question https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox I learned about HTTP 301 permanent redirect

I finally cleared the cache for the askubuntu.com url, which fixed the problem:

- open the history panel in Firefox (Ctrl + H)
- search for askubuntu.com
- right-click on the entry, and choose 'forget this site'

Comment: @StevenPenny what do you mean by "refresh firefox" ?

Comment: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings